# Validate certificate password using X509Certificate2

Tags: .net, exception, certificate, x509certificate2

I want to validate a certificate password. At this moment I have code based on handling CryptographicException and checking an exception message. But this approach is dependent on English culture info.

```
    public bool VerifyPassword(byte[] fileContent, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(fileContent, password);
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.StartsWith("The specified network password is not correct."))
            {
                return false;
            }

            throw;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I have been looking for other solution how to validate the certificate password, but without success.

What is correct approach how to validate the certificate password?

I would appreciate any idea...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After few months I found better solution (perhaps the best). It is based on HResult value of the CryptograhpicExcaption.

```
static bool VerifyPassword(byte[] fileContent, string password)
{
    try
    {
        // ReSharper disable once UnusedVariable
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(fileContent, password);
    }
    catch (CryptographicException ex)
    {
        if ((ex.HResult & 0xFFFF) == 0x56) 
        { 
            return false;
        };

        throw;
    }

    return true;
}
```

All HResults (System error codes) documentation is available on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that company I work for not allowed to use native windows API, I have a solution -> run verification on new thread with InvariantCulture. It will work on all .Net language mutations.

Here is the code example:

```
    public bool VerifyPassword(byte[] fileContent, string password)
    {
        CheckParameters(fileContent, password);
        var isPasswordVerified = false;

        var verificationThread = new Thread(() => isPasswordVerified = VerifyPasswordWithUsCulture(fileContent, password))
        {
            CurrentUICulture =  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        };

        verificationThread.Start();
        verificationThread.Join();

        return isPasswordVerified;
    }

    static bool VerifyPasswordWithUsCulture(byte[] fileContent, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            // ReSharper disable once UnusedVariable
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(fileContent, password);
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.StartsWith("The specified network password is not correct."))
            {
                return false;
            }

            throw;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [PFXVerifyPassword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387319(v=vs.85).aspx) and [PFXIsPFXBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387316(v=vs.85).aspx) native functions. Although, it requires a p/invoke, it is a real deal.

C# signature and sample code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClassLibrary1 {
    class CryptoAPI {
        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean PFXIsPFXBlob(
            [In]CRYPTOAPI_BLOB pPFX
        );
        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern Boolean PFXVerifyPassword(
            [In] CRYPTOAPI_BLOB pPFX,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            [In] String szPassword,
            [In] UInt32 dwFlags
        );
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public struct CRYPTOAPI_BLOB {
            public UInt32 cbData;
            public IntPtr pbData;
        }
    }

    public class Program {
        public static Boolean TestPfxPwd(Byte[] rawData, String password) {
            // check for input data
            if (rawData == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("rawData"); }
            // allocate a buffer in an unmanaged memory to store PFX content
            IntPtr pbData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawData.Length);
            // copy PFX content to allocated buffer
            Marshal.Copy(rawData, 0, pbData, rawData.Length);
            // instantiate CRYPTOAPI_BLOB structure as it will be used
            // to call both functions
            CryptoAPI.CRYPTOAPI_BLOB blob = new CryptoAPI.CRYPTOAPI_BLOB {
                cbData = (UInt32)rawData.Length,
                pbData = pbData
            };
            // determine if input byte array represents a PFX blob:
            if (!CryptoAPI.PFXIsPFXBlob(blob)) {
                // release unmanaged resources before leaving method
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pbData);
                throw new InvalidDataException("Input data is not valid PFX message.");
            }
            // call the PFXVerifyPassword function and store results in a temporary variable
            Boolean retValue = CryptoAPI.PFXVerifyPassword(blob, password, 0);
            // release unmanaged resources before leaving method
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pbData);
            // return pfx match status
            return retValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. I do not know about native windows api. But my company (I work for) has restrictions to avoid use native windows api.

Comment: I don't see a big issue with native functions as about a half of .NET (up to 90% of Cryptography namespace) is a wrapper for native function.

Comment: I understand. But specifically X509Certificate2 class has own imlementation in Mono. And our customers should not be dependent on windows environment. It's not out of my head. It is business. Another point of view is where do you have guarantee that Microsoft will not change native API?

Comment: About guarantees: where you have guarantee that Mono or .NET will not change their API? There are more chances that .NET and Mono change their API, than Microsoft change native function.